# How to use SELECT CONCAT() to print a message in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to write an SQL script to insert into relational table AUDIT_BOOKING information about the contents of a sample database that violates the consistency constraint:

```
"A passenger cannot book two or more different flights in the same day."
```

The script must list the outcomes of verification of the consistency constraint as a single column table with the following messages as the row in the table.

For example, if a passenger ABC who was born on 20/02/1985, has booked two flights, one flight is Q123, departure from SYD at 20/05/2020 10:30, the other flight is JS213, departure from SYD at 20/05/2020 12:30, then verification of the consistency constraint must return the following message:

```
A passenger ABC, dob is 1985-02-20, has booked tickets for flights Q123 and JS213, departure at 2020-05-20 10:30 and at 2020-05-20 12:30 in the same day.
```

I need to use a function CONCAT to create the messages like the one listed above.

When I attempt to do this, the results come back as:

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
contains nonaggregated column 'csit115.BOOKING.departTime' which is not 
functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible
with sql_mode=only_full_group_by    0.00025 sec
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT("A passenger ", name, " dob is ", DOB, " has booked tickets for flights ", flightNumber, ' departing at ', departTime, " and ", 
flightNumber, ' departing at ', departTime, " in the same day.", 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(flightNumber, ' departing at ', departTime), ' and also'))
FROM BOOKING
GROUP BY name, DOB, flightNumber, DATE(departTime)
HAVING COUNT(flightNumber)>=2;

SELECT MESSAGE
FROM AUDIT_BOOKING;
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
```

Comment: Are you really going to use the MySQL command line interface as the user terminal? I cannot see what useful purpose such an INSERT would serve.

Comment: `flightNumber, " and ", flightNumber,` - this part of concatenated data must be replaced with `GROUP_CONCAT(flightNumber SEPARATOR '" and "')`. And `flightNumber` must be excluded from GROUP BY expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are blank because no rows satisfy the HAVING; your flights would have to have the same flight number and depart at the same minute for there to be COUNT(*) 2 of them, because you group on the flight number and the date-including-the-time

Change your GROUP BY so it's not grouping on FlightNumber at all, and so it is grouping on `DATE(departTime)` rather than just `departTime`

Edit: sorry, I thought we were on "having count = 2". If you're expecting variably multiple lists of flights (so  then you'll need to do something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT('... name ... dob ... etc ...', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(flightNumber, ' departing at ', departTime) SEPARATOR ' and also ')))
```

This will list all the flights, separated by "and also", after the name/dob bit. If you're absolutely wedded to the idea of saying a list of flight numbers and then a list of dates it can be done with multiple uses of group concat; it would be advisable to use order by(and it would lengthen the query quite a bit), something like `CONCAT('flight numbers 'GROUP_CONCAT(flightnumber ORDER BY departTime,flightNumber SEPARATOR ','), ' departing at times ', GROUP_CONCAT(departTime ORDER BY departTime,flightNumber SEPARATOR ',')`

Note that this concept of "same day" is quite artificial; there's no way a person could viably get on a plane at 23:59 to Los Angeles and a plane at 00:01 the next day, to Mumbai. You might wish to later [change your query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCXUEmVoKuQT7ZdbUjmGs4/2) to use something like a window function of `WINDOW w OVER(PARTITION BY name, dob ORDER BY departTime ASC RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 1 DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` so that for every row, the DB looks back over the past 24 hours and counts the number of flights for that person in that window. If you COUNT this window you could select only those with a COUNT >1, and it would be a bit more sophisticated ("more than 1 flight in a 24 hour period") than having this hard cut at midnight/"flights on the same day" - see Will in the fiddle, where he takes two flights 2 minute apart either side of midnight

Comment: I do this and receive this error message: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 0.00069 sec

Comment: Remove the INSERT part of the query; get the select working first.. We can get the column counts right later (you're selecting a single column and trying to insert it into a table with more than one column, without specifying which column)

Comment: Ok, this ran, but it did not return anything

Comment: Then there are no people taking 3 flights in the same day

Comment: The message is for people who take 2 OR more in the same day

Comment: Ah; your `>2` clause isn't going to achieve that!

Comment: I updated the question to what I have now and what result I am receiving.

Comment: Take any "departTime" and "flight number" that is not inside a group_concat, out of your select list

Comment: I have done this but receive the same result. Here is a fiddle, this might help: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCXUEmVoKuQT7ZdbUjmGs4/1

Comment: Columns that are not mentioned in your GROUP BY must not appear anywhere other than inside the brackets of your GROUP_CONCAT(). Your fiddle has `SELECT...flightnumber...departTime...GROUP_CONCAT(...)`- if you put floightnumber/depart time like this then you must include them in the group by, which means you no longer count all flights per person per day; you count all flights per person per flight per departure per day. To work, flight number cannot be in the GROUP BY, and hence cannot appear outside an aggregating function like MIN, MAX, AVG, GROUP_CONCAT etc.

Comment: This means you have to have a group by of `name, dob, date(departuretime)` and hence any mention of flightnumber or departuretime (with a time on it) must be inside the brackets of the GROUP CONCAT. I fixed your fiddle SQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCXUEmVoKuQT7ZdbUjmGs4/1 but you still didn't have any passengers taking two+ flights in the same day. I removed all extraneous tables and then duplicated Douglas to take another flight departing a minute later, this gives a result

Comment: When I run the fiddle through the link you sent me, I still receive an error message:  Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.BOOKING.departTime' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to fiddle sites that auto save when you run the query, I didn't hit "update" after I made the changes so I ended up giving the same link back to you that you sent (i.e. your fiddle not mine - mine was lost). I did explain every change I made - nice to know the time I put into making the explanation was worth while :/ - here is the updated fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCXUEmVoKuQT7ZdbUjmGs4/6 - You did have Douglas appearing twice, but you'd changed the booking time rather than the flight time, so the query wasn't finding any flight on the same day